# Android- What's more efficient, Buttons or ListView?

Tags: android, performance, listview, button

I have an app with a complex navigation.

I have sort of a tree structure with multiple screens ( each containing ~ 8 buttons) ... (It's a tutorial app, so the user has to navigate through difficulty level button, then type button etc. to finally get to the tutorial screen)

It got me wondering, which one is more efficient and why - A bunch of buttons ins a vertical linear layout or a Simple ListView ?

Even by a few milliseconds or a few kilobytes ? I want my app to be the smallest size possible with fastest performance possible.

It's not exactly a programming problem, but I reckon this might help a lot

:-)

Thank you !

Comment: I thibk ListView is better than statuc Button Layout It's taken less time to static layout..

Comment: If it is like "select difficulty: easy, hard, ..." and you use a page of buttons for that, I'd prefer a single page of multiple [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)s.

Comment: I too opt for **Spinner** rather than using `Button or ListView`.

Comment: Some ButtonNames are rather large.. I agree a spinner is probably the most light and efficient, but it would make a rather awkward list, difficult to read and well big buttons are easier to click...